# Merge 2 Dataframes based on all permutations of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, permutation

I am new to Python & programming in general so I hope this question makes sense.

I have df1 which contains transactional data with someone's full name. This isn't standard so it can be entered *First Name Last Name* **or** *Last Name First Name* usually. I then have df2 which is HR data with the employees name as per the system.

I am looking to merge df2 into df1 based on all the possible permutations of how the name could be entered, and end up with a result like df3.

The tables can be quite large, so am looking for something efficient if possible. I've researched itertools and the permutation function which I thought might be useful. But I am having issues figuring out how to "loop" over each row and try to merge it to df2 based on the different orders the name could be entered in.

```
# import pandas as pd
import pandas as pd
  
# creating data frame
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[['sravan Sudheer'], 
                        ['sudheer sravan'],
                        ['vani radha'], ],
                  columns=['name'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = [['Sudheer sravan', 'analyst'],
                           ['radha vani','lead'], ],
                  columns = ['hr_name', 'title'])

df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=[['sravan Sudheer', 'analyst'], 
                        ['sudheer sravan', 'analyst'],
                        ['radha vani', 'lead'], ],
                  columns=['name', 'title'])
```

Comment: whatever method you use, it is recommended that you assign a **unique name** at the outset as this will make life easier (more logical) going forwards.

Answer (score 0):

In order to give a solution with `all permutations of a column`, one would need to have access to the real dataframe. As one only has access to a sample, my answer will consider only that sample.

For that, one will create the columns `first_name` and `last_name` to store the value of the string in the column `name` and then merge on both columns.

Let us start by doing that to `df1`

```
df1 = df1.assign(first_name = df1['name'].str.split(' ').str[0].str.lower(), last_name = df1['name'].str.split(' ').str[1].str.lower())

[Out]:

             name first_name last_name
0  sravan Sudheer     sravan   sudheer
1  sudheer sravan    sudheer    sravan
2      vani radha       vani     radha
```

Now, moving on to `df2`, and considering that the `first_name` appears after, one will need to change `str[0]` to `str[1]` for the `first_name`, and change the `last_name` to `str[0]`

```
df2 = df2.assign(first_name = df2['hr_name'].str.split(' ').str[1].str.lower(), last_name = df2['hr_name'].str.split(' ').str[0].str.lower())

[Out]:

          hr_name    title first_name last_name
0  Sudheer sravan  analyst     sravan   sudheer
1      radha vani     lead       vani     radha
```

Now, let us do the merge.

If one does a simple left join on `first_name` and `last_name`, one will get the following

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on=['first_name', 'last_name'])

[Out]:

             name first_name last_name         hr_name    title
0  sravan Sudheer     sravan   sudheer  Sudheer sravan  analyst
1  sudheer sravan    sudheer    sravan             NaN      NaN
2      vani radha       vani     radha      radha vani     lead
```

---

**Notes:**

- Assuming that OP doesn't want `NaN` values in the `title` column, and, assuming that `svran sudheer` is the same as `sudheer sravan`, one can change it's value with

  ```
   df3.loc[df3['name'] == 'sudheer sravan', 'title'] = 'analyst'

  [Out]:
                name first_name last_name         hr_name    title
  0  sravan Sudheer     sravan   sudheer  Sudheer sravan  analyst
  1  sudheer sravan    sudheer    sravan             NaN  analyst
  2      vani radha       vani     radha      radha vani     lead
  ```

or by shifting the value of the previous row to the current as follows

```
df3['title'] = df3['title'].fillna(df3['title'].shift(1))
```

- If one doesn't want the column `hr_name` in `df3`, then

  ```
  df3 = df3.drop(columns=['hr_name'])

  [Out]:
               name first_name last_name    title
  0  sravan Sudheer     sravan   sudheer  analyst
  1  sudheer sravan    sudheer    sravan  analyst
  2      vani radha       vani     radha     lead
  ```